# Creating/Writing a text/xml file using javascript without using ActiveX

Tags: javascript

Can  anyone guide me to create/write a text/xml file using the javascript coding but without making use of the ActicveX controls.

The purpose of overriding the ActiveX is, i want to run the html page on Chrome only.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write local files using client-side JavaScript.

Comment: You can, with the new HTML5 File API - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: That just gives you a virtual filesystem, not access to the real one (at least not to arbitrary/user-specified) paths.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 File API: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

BlobBuilder API: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side

Answer (score 0):

you can’t do that. JavaScript is not allowed to access the client’s file system (ActiveX being the exception, obviously)

besides that, fopen(), fread() & fclose() are typical PHP functions (not sure about ActiveX, but it doesn’t seems like they belong there, too)